# Date/Datetime of Matplotlib not compatible with those of Pandas/Python3?

Tags: matplotlib

Is Datetime in Matplotlib different from that of the Datetime used in Pandas or Python3? Does it need to be explicitly converted using Matplotlib functions such as `date2num`?

Background:

[matplotlib.dates](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#module-matplotlib.dates) says it uses floating point from `0001-01-01 UTC`.

> Matplotlib represents dates using floating point numbers specifying
>   the number of days since 0001-01-01 UTC, plus 1. For example,
>   0001-01-01, 06:00 is 1.25, not 0.25. Values < 1, i.e. dates before
>   0001-01-01 UTC are not supported.

[Python Data Visualization with Matplotlib](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/python-data-visualization-matplotlib-2x) says:

> we need to convert the values to float numbers supported by Matplotlib.

```
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import pandas as pd

# Convert Date column from string to Python datetime object,
# then to float number that is supported by Matplotlib.
stock_df["Datetime"] = date2num(pd.to_datetime(stock_df["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d").tolist())
```

Comment: Yes, it is different. You found the definition yourself. But no, in most cases, you do not need to convert to this format. Matplotlib by now understands python datetime and numpy.datetime64 perfectly fine and does the conversion internally. You do not show the usecase from the example, so one cannot know if this conversion is strictly necessary or not.